# How to view a list of comments on a pdf in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-comments

I am trying to view a list of all comments, including the resolved comments, in Google Drive. For Google Docs, there is a button to view all of the comments, including resolved ones (https://gsuitetips.com/tips/docs/see-all-comments-in-a-google-doc-even-resolved-ones/). I can't find such a button for pdfs uploaded to Google Drive at all though, so is there a way for me to find a list of all comments for those documents?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

1. Go to drive.google.com and find your PDF
2. Open the PDF

This could open the "preview" view. If this doesn't show the comments button,

3. Click on the More (three dots) button
4. Clic the open in a new window

This will open the "normal view". If this doesn't show the comments button, then check that you are using a supported web browser.

Comment: I do see the comments button, that's not the problem. The problem is that I cannot see a list of comments, including the resolved ones.